# Get Selenium Webdriver and nUnit test cases from defined CSV file

Tags: .net, csv, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Is it possible to include a CSV file that outlines all the test cases I want to run?

For example, at the moment I have dozens of nUnit  methods:

```
<Test()>
Public Sub Login_CanLogin()
    Assert.IsTrue(Pages.loginPage.CanLogin(True))
End Sub
```

I want to have this test method defined in a row in an external CSV file that the framework initially reads to determine if it should be run or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypothetically, you could create a custom attribute, analogous to PlatformAttribute, which decides whether to run a test on the current platform. Your attribute would have to be placed on each test. It would examine the CSV file to decide whether to allow that test to run.

I spelled out how you **might** do this so that you will hopefully realize it's not a very good idea.

Basically the job of the framework is to run the tests it is told to run. It's the job of whatever is calling into the framework to provide that direction. The console runner, for example, has the ability to use a list of tests in a file and instruct the framework to run those tests.

Look to whatever runner you are using for the way to specify a list of tests.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am using the vstest runner. Your advice led me to the **/Tests:** command line attribute (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx).